# Some doubts about how correctly compare the staging area content with the last commit using GIT?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-stage

I am pretty new in **GIT** and I have the following doubt about the correct use of the **git diff --staged** that should compare the **staging area** content with the last commit.

So I obtain this output:

```
$ git diff --staged
diff --git a/game.js b/game.js
index 49bf5ea..0783175 100644
--- a/game.js
+++ b/game.js
@@ -421,6 +421,7 @@ Ship = function () {
     }
     if (KEY_STATUS.space) {
       if (this.delayBeforeBullet <= 0) {
+               this.delayBeforeBullet = 10;
        // added to fix the bug !!!
         for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
           if (!this.bullets[i].visible) {
             SFX.laser();
@@ -539,6 +540,7 @@ BigAlien = function () {

     this.delayBeforeBullet -= delta;
     if (this.delayBeforeBullet <= 0) {
+       //if (this.delayBeforeBullet = 10) {
       this.delayBeforeBullet = 22;
       for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
         if (!this.bullets[i].visible) {

Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/WS_vari/version-control/asteroids ((3884eab
...))
```

So what exactly means this output? I think that it means that, in the **staging area** I have add these 2 lines:

1)

```
 + this.delayBeforeBullet = 10; // added to fix the bug !!!
```

2)

```
+       //if (this.delayBeforeBullet = 10) {
```

that I don't have in the last commit.

Is it my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's more accurate to say that in the staging-area, you have a version of the file that has those two extra lines.

The staging-area contains complete files, not just differences from other files.  It has complete copies of other files as well; they're just identical to the versions of the files in the `HEAD` commit, so `git diff` doesn't show them.